# Was hero worship the same as god worship?

Tags: greek, homer, iliad, worship

In Greek Mythology, their are a few special heroes (Diomedes being one) who, after Death claims them, have a shrine/temple build in their honor and for worship. Was the worship they received similar/same to that of a god, or completely different? In what ways?

Answer (score 2):

In Proclusean hierarchy heroes were higher ranking than mortals, purified souls, daimons, lower than angels, archangels and Deities. They received worship and commemoration alike to the Gods. In fact they were - for example - Herculean mysteries and Herculean temples, stemming from the Eleusis rites (Heracles was a succesful initiate of these mystery schools). It is difficult to tell from a qualitative perspective what was the cognitive and spiritual way of expressing the worship, but I guess that in these days, when mixing and exchanging Deities was common, one might even have such instances when a hero received greater worship than a higher Deity in a different region.